# Combine multiple SQL queries in SQL Server 2008 into a datatable on ASP.NET using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datatable

I am trying to combine 2 big SQL queries into one datatable, so I can load it on the webpage.

Query #1:

```
select
    isnull(SALES_NUM4, '') SalesNo, 
    count(CUS_ID) NumOfCust, 
    count(distinct sales_num) NumOfRep
from 
    (select 
         SALES_NUM4, CUS_ID, SLS_TYPE, SALES_NUM 
     from customer

     union

     select 
         SALES_NUM4, CUS_ID, SLS_TYPE, SALES_NUM 
     from omsdata7.dbo.customer) a
where 
    SALES_NUM4 != '' and SLS_TYPE = '1'
group by 
    SALES_NUM4
order by 
    SALES_NUM4
```

Query #2:

```
select 
    isnull(SALES_NUM4, '') SalesNo, 
    count(ORD_NUM) MTD_Ord, 
    convert(decimal(10, 2), sum(ORD_AMT)) MTD_Amt
from 
    (select 
         SALES_NUM4, ORD_DT, ORD_NUM, ORD_AMT 
     from orders

     union

     select 
         SALES_NUM4, ORD_DT, ORD_NUM, ORD_AMT 
     from omsdata7.dbo.orders) a
where 
    DATEADD(day, ORD_DT-4, '1801-01-01') >= DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
    and DATEADD(day, ORD_DT-4, '1801-01-01') < getdate()
    and SALES_NUM4 != ''
group by 
    SALES_NUM4
order by 
    SALES_NUM4
```

Comment: do you want to combine the 2 queries using SQL Join or do you want to merge the datatable returned by each query into 1 datatable in C#?

Comment: @Code.me I think both way will work, but I prefer the combined query way since that would reduce the sql connection time.

Comment: @prashanth the question is how to combine two queries above? or Can you can display two queries in one single datatable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will work. I am joining the sub queries.

```
select  isnull(a.SALES_NUM4, '') SalesNo, 
        count(CUS_ID) NumOfCust, 
        count(distinct sales_num) NumOfRep,
        count(ORD_NUM) MTD_Ord, 
        convert(decimal(10, 2), sum(ORD_AMT)) MTD_Amt
from 
    (select SALES_NUM4, CUS_ID, SLS_TYPE, SALES_NUM 
     from   customer
     union
     select SALES_NUM4, CUS_ID, SLS_TYPE, SALES_NUM 
     from   omsdata7.dbo.customer) as a
    inner join
    (select SALES_NUM4, ORD_DT, ORD_NUM, ORD_AMT 
     from   orders
     union
     select SALES_NUM4, ORD_DT, ORD_NUM, ORD_AMT 
     from   omsdata7.dbo.orders) as b
    on a.SALES_NUM4 = b.SALES_NUM4
where   a.SALES_NUM4 != '' and SLS_TYPE = '1' 
        and DATEADD(day, ORD_DT-4, '1801-01-01') >= DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
        and DATEADD(day, ORD_DT-4, '1801-01-01') < getdate()
group by    a.SALES_NUM4
order by   a.SALES_NUM4
```

Comment: It gives me "Column 'a.SALES_NUM4' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." But I solved it myself using sub query too. Thank you so much.

Comment: I added the group by clause now.

Comment: If this helped you, please accept and upvote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    -- QUERY 1 #tmpReport1 with respect the grouping and sort order    

        select
            isnull(SALES_NUM4, '') SalesNo, 
            count(CUS_ID) NumOfCust, 
            count(distinct sales_num) NumOfRep
        into #tmpReport1
        from 
            (select 
                 SALES_NUM4, CUS_ID, SLS_TYPE, SALES_NUM 
             from customer

             union

             select 
                 SALES_NUM4, CUS_ID, SLS_TYPE, SALES_NUM 
             from omsdata7.dbo.customer) a
        where 
            SALES_NUM4 != '' and SLS_TYPE = '1'
        group by 
            SALES_NUM4
        order by 
            SALES_NUM4

    -- QUERY 2 BUILD #tmpReport2 with respect the grouping and sort order
    select 
        isnull(SALES_NUM4, '') SalesNo, 
        count(ORD_NUM) MTD_Ord, 
        convert(decimal(10, 2), sum(ORD_AMT)) MTD_Amt
    into #tmpReport2
    from 
        (select 
             SALES_NUM4, ORD_DT, ORD_NUM, ORD_AMT 
         from orders

         union

         select 
             SALES_NUM4, ORD_DT, ORD_NUM, ORD_AMT 
         from omsdata7.dbo.orders) a
    where 
        DATEADD(day, ORD_DT-4, '1801-01-01') >= DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
        and DATEADD(day, ORD_DT-4, '1801-01-01') < getdate()
        and SALES_NUM4 != ''
    group by 
        SALES_NUM4
    order by 
        SALES_NUM4

-- combine both tables in here
select * from #tmpReport1
union all
select * from #tmpReport2

-- drop temps
drop table #tmpReport1
drop table #tmpReport2
```

Hope I understood your question correctly?

EDIT : Join horizontally, then same script above except for

```
-- combine both tables in here
select * from #tmpReport1
union all
select * from #tmpReport2
```

Change to

```
-- combine both tables horizontally here
select 
   tmp1.*
   ,tmp2.* 
from #tmpReport1 tmp1
full join #tmpReport2 tmp2
ON
   tmp1.SalesNo = tmp2.SalesNo
```

and simply identify your columns based on your specifications.

Comment: SQL throws me a "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'."

Comment: My bad, union all doesn't work after a function, so I turned it into a table first before union.

Comment: only returned first table, but still missing "count(ORD_NUM) MTD_Ord" and "convert(decimal(10,2), sum(ORD_AMT)) MTD_Amt"

Comment: This almost worked, except it returns John    15, James 13 in 1st and 2nd row from first big query and John    3,  James     7 in 3rd and 4th row from second query.

Comment: It was my fault I did not specify I want to join horizontally as "Join"

Answer (score 0):

```
select isnull(SALES_NUM4,'') SalesNo, count(CUS_ID) NumOfCust, count(distinct SALES_NUM) NumOfReps, MAX(b.MTD_Ord) MTD_Ord, MAX(b.MTD_Amt) MTD_Amt
from (
select SALES_NUM4, CUS_ID, SLS_TYPE, SALES_NUM from customer
union
select SALES_NUM4, CUS_ID, SLS_TYPE, SALES_NUM from omsdata7.dbo.customer
where SLS_TYPE = '1'
) a
Left join 
(select isnull(SALES_NUM4,'') SalesNo, count(ORD_NUM) MTD_Ord, sum(ORD_AMT) MTD_Amt
from (
select SALES_NUM4, ORD_DT, ORD_NUM, ORD_AMT from orders
union
select SALES_NUM4, ORD_DT, ORD_NUM, ORD_AMT from omsdata7.dbo.orders
) b1
where DATEADD(day, ORD_DT-4, '1801-01-01') >= DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
and DATEADD(day, ORD_DT-4, '1801-01-01') < getdate() 
group by SALES_NUM4 
) b on a.SALES_NUM4 = b.SalesNo 
where SALES_NUM4 != ''
group by SALES_NUM4
order by SALES_NUM4
```